# Dropdown menu in Javascript doesn't load data

Tags: javascript, function

The is the HTML page works and is formatted to pull the code from other JavaScript pages.
Dropdown menu loads from first function (`loadRestaurants`).
When clicking on the dropdown menu the webpage doesn't switch to new information that displays the data from the tables.
The JavaScript function (`loadMenu`) doesn't load the information from the tables.

```js
function loadRestaurants() {
  var parentElement = document.getElementById("restaurant");
  parentElement.innerHTML = "";
  for (var restaurantId in restaurantCollection) {
    var restaurantObj = restaurantCollection[restaurantId];
    var restaurantName = restaurantObj["name"];
    var restaurantNo = restaurantObj["id"];
    parentElement.innerHTML += '<option id="' + restaurantNo + '" value="' + restaurantNo + '">' + restaurantName + '</option>';
  };
}

//View All Restaurants Page
function loadMenu() {
  var restaurantNo = document.getElementById("restaurant").value;
  var foodItemsTable = document.getElementById("fooditems");

  var tbodyElement = document.getElementById("foodItem");
  console.log(foodItemsCollection)

  for (var fooditemId in foodItemsCollection) {
    var fooditem = foodItemsCollection[fooditemId];
    var htmlText =
      `<td>${fooditem["id"]}</td><td>${fooditem["title"]}</td><td>${fooditem["description"]}</td><td>${fooditem["inStock"]}</td><td>${fooditem["isVeg"]}</td><td>${fooditem["category"]}</td><td>${fooditem["cuisine"]}</td><td><img src="${fooditem["image"]}"  style="width:80px;height:80px"></td><td><button>Edit</button></td></tr>`;
    tbodyElement.innerHTML += htmlText;

    var tbodyElement = document.getElementById("resturantNo");
    console.log(restaurantCollection)

    for (var restaurantId in restaurantCollection) {
      var restaurantitem = restaurantCollection[restaurantId];
      var htmlText = `<td>${restaurantitem["id"]}</td><td>${restaurantitem["name"]}</td><td>${restaurant["addr"]}</td><td>${restaurant["contact"]}</td><td>${fooditem["isVeg"]}</td><td>${fooditem["category"]}</td><td><img src="${restaurant["image"]}" style="width:80px;height:80px"></td><td><button>Edit</button></td></tr>`;
      tbodyElement.innerHTML += htmlText;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>List Food Menu</title>
  <script src="../admin_js/restaurantsData.js"></script>
  <script src="../admin_js/fooditemsData.js"></script>
  <script src="../admin_js/menuData.js"></script>
  <script src="../admin_js/adminmenu.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../admin_styles/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../admin_styles/productsstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button class="home-button"><a href="../admin_views/admin_page.html">Home</a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="container">
      <form name="ViewRestaurantMenu" id="RestaurantMenu" action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="restaurant">Select Restaurant</label>
            <select name="restaurant" id="restaurant" onfocus="loadRestaurants();" onchange="listMenu();"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <table id="foodtable" class="table">
            <tbody id="fooditems">
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you have some sample data `restaurantCollection` we might use to "fake" the data being retrieved?

Comment: var restaurantCollection = {
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Food Town",
        "addr": "Abbey Street, Berkshire",
        "contact": "27287",
        "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517248135467-4c7edcad34c4?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
    },

Answer (score 0):

Simplified answer to loop on an array of objects to add them:

```js
const foodPlace = document.getElementById("restaurant");
let places = [{
    name: "Feed Em",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Eat Here",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Bills Bar",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Ann's place",
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Slophouse",
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: "Pizza Hause",
    id: 6
  }
];

function loadRestaurants(restaurantCollection) {
  const selectList = document.getElementById("restaurant");
  selectList.innerHTML = "";
  restaurantCollection.forEach((restaurant) => {
    let opt = new Option(restaurant.name, restaurant.id);
    selectList.appendChild(opt);
  });
}

loadRestaurants(places);
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="home-button"><a href="../admin_views/admin_page.html">Home</a></button>
</div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <form name="ViewRestaurantMenu" id="RestaurantMenu" action="">
      <h1>Menu</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="restaurant">Select Restaurant</label>
          <select name="restaurant" id="restaurant"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <table id="foodtable" class="table">
          <tbody id="fooditems">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Just substitute your object names for an array of whatever you want and this should work.